# What is the correct way to set status code and data in jax-rs Respone?

Tags: jax-rs

**Question 1**

Can you please tell me which of the following code is appropriate?
Is there any difference between the two codes?

**Question 2**

Is it OK to use `Response.status (int status)` with other status codes (eg 201)?
Is there a difference with the method dedicated to each status code (eg `Response.created (URI location)` for 201)?

Below is the sample code.

**case1**

```
Response.ok(jsonText).build();
```

**case2**

```
Response.status(Response.Status.OK).entity(jsonText).build();
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference. Taking a look into the implementation, you have these methods:

```
public static ResponseBuilder ok(Object entity) {
    ResponseBuilder b = ok();
    b.entity(entity);
    return b;
}
```

```
public static ResponseBuilder ok() {
    return status(Status.OK);
}
```

You could simplify this to

```
public static ResponseBuilder ok(Object entity) {
    ResponseBuilder b = status(Status.OK);
    b.entity(entity);
    return b;
}
```

which is the same like

```
public static ResponseBuilder ok(Object entity) {
    return status(Status.OK).entity(entity);
}
```

`Status.OK` actually is `Response.Status.OK`, so `ok(entity)` is the same as `status(Response.Status.OK).entity(entity)`.

> Is it OK to use Response.status (int status) with other status codes (eg 201)?

Absolutely.

> Is there a difference with the method dedicated to each status code (eg Response.created (URI location) for 201)?

Have a look in the method implementation like in the example above and you will see if there are any differences or additional steps.

Comment: Thank you very much. Let's check the implementation.